# How to show selected value on toggle in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I used toggle in my app.I want to show the selected value on toggle every time when i load the page.

**Problem :**  I select true but whenever i load the page it displays false.

**html code**

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="isToggled" (ionChange)="YES1()"></ion-toggle>
```

**ts code**

```
public isToggled: boolean;
YES1()
  {
    console.log("Toggled: "+ this.isToggled);
    if(this.isToggled == true)
    {
      console.log('true');
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('false');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll always show false because you haven't initialized your property with a value, so it's undefined and the toggle'll stay false everytime you load your page. If you want to always show as toggled/true simple do

```
public isToggled: boolean = true;
```

Angular doesn't stores the value on it's on, whenever you unload that page from the stack or reload the page the values are reseted.

If you want to save the value to use it latter i recommend using a database or at least some local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to record the state and retrieve it on page load. Use `ngOnInit()`

You can also do that in the constructor, but it's not recommended.

You can store the data in

- a service
- LocalStorage
- global variable (like a custom Globals class that has public static members)
- etc

Are you loading the page brand new? Or are you putting a view on top and then popping the view? If you are popping the value should stay.

Like Gabriel said, if you are loading the page new then you have lost the previous state. Grab the state from somewhere else on load.